# How to solve this nonseparable second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this second-order non-linear ODE?

$$ r’’ -2 \frac{r’^2}{r^3} - \frac{1}{3} \lambda ~ r =0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \star $$

where $\lambda$ is a constant. In case if the third term is not there, i.e., $\lambda =0$, I can use the first procedure mentioned in this thread

[solving second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69577/solving-second-order-nonlinear-ordinary-differential-equation)

But now as the third term exists, the separation of variables is not possible. Here is what I have tried:

Let $\nu=r’= \frac{dr}{dx}$

then $ r’’ = \frac{d\nu}{dx} = \frac{d\nu}{dr} ~ \frac{dr}{dx} = \nu \frac{d\nu}{dr} $, substitute in $\star$

$$ \nu \frac{d\nu}{dr} = 2 \frac{\nu^2}{r^3}+ \frac{1}{3} \lambda r 
$$

Here I think the separation of variables isn't applicable. So any idea how to solve this, or an alternative way.

Any help is appreciated!